# How to solve 'Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget error' in Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget

In my app I created an Elevated Button to pop up a bottom sheet. In onpressed I used:

```
UtilsUtils.bottomSheet(widget.context, widget.content)
```

But when I pressed this button I get 'Exception caught by widgets library.Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.' the error.

```
static bottomSheet(
      BuildContext context, String content,
      ) {
    return showModalBottomSheet(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20))),
        isScrollControlled: true .
        ,
        context: context,
        builder: ((context) {
         return Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
            DraggableScrollableSheet(
              expand: false,
              initialChildSize: 0.4,
              maxChildSize: 0.8,
              minChildSize: 0.3,
              builder: (context, scrollController) {
                return SingleChildScrollView(
                  controller: scrollController,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                          child: IconButton(
                            onPressed: ,(){}
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.edit,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          content,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: -15,
              child: Container(
                width: 60,
                height: 7,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
        }));
  }
```

So how can I solve this error? Because of which widget the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

My Friend this error happens because of your positioning of the `Positioned` widget inside the Stack. you just provided `top` but not `right`, `left` or `bottom` that is making error.

EDIT: here is completed code that is working fine for me:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
 
  runApp(const MyScreen(
  ));

}

class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyScreen> createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Builder(
              builder: (context) => InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  bottomSheet(context, 'hello');
                },
                child: const Text('hello'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  bottomSheet(BuildContext context, String content) {
    return showModalBottomSheet(
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20)),
      ),
      isScrollControlled: true,
      context: context,
      builder: ((context) {
        return Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
            DraggableScrollableSheet(
              expand: false,
              initialChildSize: 0.4,
              maxChildSize: 0.8,
              minChildSize: 0.3,
              builder: (context, scrollController) {
                return SingleChildScrollView(
                  controller: scrollController,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                          child: IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            icon: const Icon(
                              Icons.edit,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          content,
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: -15,
              left: 0, // Add this line
              right: 0, // Add this line
              child: Container(
                width: 60,
                height: 7,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

this code is the update of your code to solve your problem.

happy coding...

Comment: @Unfortunately I still get the error.

Comment: hey my friend, I've Edited the answer to the whole code of mine that I'm using and it is working as well as I put the screenshot, when you click on hello Text the bottomSheet comes up, test the whole code again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be with the **Stack** widget that you are using as the parent widget. The **Stack** widget requires its children to have constraints set on them so that it can position them correctly. The **SingleChildScrollView** widget that you are using as a child widget of the **DraggableScrollableSheet** does not have any constraints set on it, so the **Stack** widget cannot position it correctly.

A possible fix would be by adding a **SizedBox** widget as a child of the **SingleChildScrollView** widget and set its height to a fixed value or use a widget that can set its constraints properly, such as the **Expanded** widget.

Here's the code:

```
static bottomSheet(BuildContext context, String content) {
  return showModalBottomSheet(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20)),
),
    isScrollControlled: true,
    context: context,
    builder: ((context) {
      return Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          DraggableScrollableSheet(
            expand: false,
            initialChildSize: 0.4,
            maxChildSize: 0.8,
            minChildSize: 0.3,
            builder: (context, scrollController) {
              return Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.edit,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        controller: scrollController,
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                          child: Text(
                            content,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: -15,
            child: Container(
              width: 60,
              height: 7,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }),
  );
}
```

Hope this helps.